# Photoshop Actions Now Prompting for User Input?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I have a set of Photoshop Actions with many steps which are a vital part of my workflow. Recently, after upgrading to Photoshop CS6, it prompts me for user input at various stages which the Action steps never required before.

Contrary to what you might expect, none of the 'Toggle Dialogue On/Off' boxes are checked 'On' for any of the action steps. I have verified this several times.

I am trying to figure out a way to stop this behavior as it adds a lot more requirements on my attention than previously and I rely on these actions heavily for creating artwork.

Has there been a change in the actions system between CS5 and CS6 that might be causing this? 
Does anyone know how to stop this?

Any help or insight would make my life a lot easier!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have isolated the cause of the problem:

The Photoshop file I was running the Action Set on was in CMYK color format while the previous files I had used it on were in RGB color format.

The Action set relies on several steps which make adjustments to attributes such as Levels and Hue/Saturation which require different definition values in a file which has 4 channels for color (CMYK) instead of 3 (RGB). This caused the Action to halt and prompt for user input at each step of this type.

I have verified this as the problem by changing the file from CMYK to RGB and the problem no longer occurs. The Action Set runs flawlessly.

So, for anyone experiencing similar results, something like this might be the cause.

Contrary to my original assumptions, the issue is unrelated to which version of Photoshop I used.